# Microsoft Store fails to install app after app has been uninstalled

Tags: xamarin

I am a Xamarin developer and putting my app on the Microsoft Store for the first time.
I initially set up the submission for access only with a link (not published on the store for general audience).  This was to allow myself to test the behavior of my app with the store prior to making it visible on the store for all.
The app is set up as a free app with in-app purchases.
So, this is what I have done:

1. "Get" the app with the link provided for the app.
2. Purchase the app using the in-app purchasing.  This works fine.
3. Uninstall the app.
4. Using the link for the app I try to reinstall it.  The link shows that I have purchased the app but there is no "Get" button.
5. I restart the computer.
6. Using the link for the app I try to reinstall the app again.  This time there is a "Get" button and there is also an indication that I have purchased the app.  This looks promising, but when I press "Get" and enter the 6-digit code sent to me by the store, the app is  not installed.

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

BTW, I am doing all of this on my development computer.

See above for details of what I tried and what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be caused by the damage of Windows Store cache. You can try to reset the MicroSoft Store and install the app again.

Here is the method to [reset the MicroSoft Store](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-store-says-i-have-an-app-installed-when-i/93a07f3c-bfe0-4596-8270-9c9a27d5585c).